# Red5 Websocket chat application support multiple chat rooms

Tags: websocket, red5

Using Red5 and

https://github.com/Red5/red5-websocket-chat

I try to do a basic chat.
It works ok for a example channel

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://serverIP:80/chat', 'chat');
```

Is there any way to do something similar to chat rooms using Red5 Websocket chat?
An example I want to do from JavaScript is using URL:

```
var socketRoom1 = new WebSocket('ws://serverIP:80/chat/Room1', 'chat');

var socketRoom2 = new WebSocket('ws://serverIP:80/chat/Room2', 'chat');

...

 var socketRoomN = new WebSocket('ws://serverIP:80/chat/RoomN', 'chat');
```

**or using Protocol:**

```
var socketRoom1 = new WebSocket('ws://serverIP:80/chat', 'Room1');

var socketRoom2 = new WebSocket('ws://serverIP:80/chat', 'Room2');

...

var socketRoomN = new WebSocket('ws://serverIP:80/chat', 'RoomN');
```

But I only can make it works in JavaScript with that:

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://serverIP:80/chat', 'chat');
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to do this by integrating with the Red5 scopes and creating the new scopes as needed. Scopes are basically interchangeable with "rooms" or contexts. This endeavor will require that you learn at least at a basic level how the scopes work. You'll also need to modify / extend the listener to add/remove the scopes as needed and to route your messages.

https://github.com/Red5/red5-websocket-chat/blob/master/src/main/java/org/red5/demos/chat/WebSocketChatDataListener.java

Here's some additional reading regarding scopes / rooms:

http://ria101.wordpress.com/2010/03/09/red5-cabin-fever-advanced-scope-and-room-management/

http://gregoire.org/2009/04/07/on-demand-room-scope-creation/